# Pre-populate a PowerForm Envelope field using form values

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I'm following the PowerForm docs on the following guide 
https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/PowerForms_User_Guide.pdf

I need to save custom metadata inside the envelope, such as the User ID, so I can later
process the envelope.

I want to be able to populate a custom envelope field, using a form submission like the following:

```
 <form action="https://demo.docusign.net/MEMBER/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=<ID>" method="POST"> 
   <label for="email">Email Address: </label><input type="text" name="Signer1_Email" id="email"/> 
   <label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="Signer 1_UserName" id="name"/>
   <label for="order">Order Number: </label><input type="text" name="OrderNumber" id="order"/>
   <input class="form_submit" type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Is this possible?

From the heading inside the docs:

**Populating custom envelope fields in a Web PowerForm**

Example: EnvelopeField_Region=Northwest

I have tried the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="EnvelopeField_orgid" value="xyz" id="EnvelopeField_orgid"/>
<input type="hidden" name="EnvelopeField_orgids" value="aaa" id="orgid"/>
```

Also, I have tried navigating the docusign command center and have not found any options to add custom envelope fields to a Template or PowerForm.

Comment: I have also tried appending the following to the url as an argument: &EnvelopeField_userid=34 and no success.

I also went inside the Docusign command center and downloaded the 'Form Data' pertaining to the Envelope and no EnvelopeField data is in there.

Answer (score 1):

What if you post the data and redirect to a built link off of that data (I'm not sure what' youre using besides HTML). I don't believe you can POST directly from a form to a PowerForm link the way it needs to be formatted.

Here's a quick PHP/JS example of what I'm referring to:

```
<?
if($_POST){
  $baseUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/MEMBER/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=" . $_POST['PowerFormId'];
  $EnvelopeField_orgid = $_POST['EnvelopeField_orgid'];
  $EnvelopeField_orgids = $_POST['EnvelopeField_orgids'];
  $link = $baseUrl . "&EnvelopeField_orgid=" . $EnvelopeField_orgid . "&EnvelopeField_orgids" . $EnvelopeField_orgids;
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.top.location.href='<?echo $link;?>'</script>
  <?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

We were able to pass parameters to a Powerform. Below is a sample syntax of how we did it.

https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=50ac80ac-a63c-40c7-b2f4-25e93806b647&Signer1_Email=test@test.com&AccountName=Test&&Signer1_UserName=Test+User

Comment: This is the URL of the Powerform and anything preceded by "&" are the custom fields on the form that we wanted to prepopulate.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Oh not sure what you mean but here's the breakdown of that link:   PowerformURL&Role_CustomTag=Value    Hope that helps!